# jQuery selector question

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I'm in a bit of a dilemma. I need to select div tags based on whether their children have a certain class. This is a code example of the DOM structure:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="one">
         <p>This is item one</p>
         <p class="special">This is a description</p>
    </div>

    <div id="two">
         <p>This is item one</p>
         <p>This is a description</p>
    </div>

    <div id="three">
         <p>This is item one</p>
         <p class="special">This is a description</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

So, what I want to select is a div tag that doesn't have a paragraph with a class of "special", and in the example above, that would be second div tag (#two).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `:not` and `:has` [selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

```
$('div:not(:has(p.special))')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children("p.special").length == 0;
})
```